# Unable to read file using fread in C

Tags: c, fread

I am trying to read a file "file.raw" and 4 bytes at a time to an array and check if it has the particular 4 byte signature I am looking for.  I am having trouble with this. The value of result I get is 0, instead of 4 when using fread.

```
#include<stdint.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE; 

int main(void)
{
    size_t result;
    FILE *inptr = fopen("file.raw","r+");
    //Check if file can be opened.
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("File Open Error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    long int x = 0;

    while(!feof(inptr))
    {
        // Make space for reading in to an array
        BYTE *array = (BYTE *) malloc(10);
        if(array == NULL)
        {
            printf("Array Initialization Error\n");
            return -1;
        }

        result = fread(array,1,4,inptr);
        //Exit if file not read. ** This is where I can't get past.
        if(result != 4)
        {
            printf("File Read Error\n");
            printf("%d\n",result);
            free(array);
            fclose(inptr);
            return -1;
        }

        //Compare strings

        if(memcmp(array,"0xffd8ffe0",4)==0)
        {
            printf("File Start found\n");
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            printf("%p\n",inptr);
            free(array);
            fclose(inptr);
            return 0;
        }
        x++;
        free(array);
    }

    printf("%p\n",inptr);
    printf("%ld\n",x);
    fclose(inptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `ferror(inptr)` give you?

Comment: Check `feof()` and `ferror()` to determine the cause: either EOF or a read failure. If a read failure check `errno` to obtain reason for failure.

Comment: Also writing `while(!feof(inptr))` is completely broken. `feof` is only meaningful **after** the read operation has been done...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that it doesn't fail on the first iteration of the `while` loop, but rather keeps  reading the file until you reach end of the file, at which point `fread()` returns 0 and your program exits.

The reason it's not finding the signature is this:

```
memcmp(array,"0xffd8ffe0",4)==0
```

That `memcmp()` call is almost certainly not what you want (it's looking for the sequence of ASCII characters `'0'`, `'x'`, `'f'` and `'f'`).

PS As noted by @Mat in the comments, for maximum portability you should open the file in binary mode (`"r+b"` instead of `"r+"`).

Comment: Very very likely. The lack of "b" in the open mode could be problematic on some platforms too.

Comment: @aix, You are right. Thanks. What should be used instead of memcmp to find if 0xffd8ffe0 is in my file?

Comment: @kevin: The `memcmp()` per se isn't the problem, it's the string that you give as the second argument. You probably want to create a char array along the lines of `char header[] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0}` and use that in the `memcmp()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file in binary mode (`"r+b"`) instead of text mode (`"r+"`).  You're probably being undone by unintentional CRLF conversions, messing up your binary data.